# ACI Virtual Nodes pods failure giving "ProviderFailed" error

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I am getting the "ProviderFailed" error message when running an Azure Container Instance (ACI) container in a virtual node.

Comment: Which service do you use? AKS with the virtual node? And which document do you follow and what steps did you do?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with Fluentd, it doesn't run on virtual nodes due to same error and so no logs are found in Elastic Search.